# JMeter (Sampler 'WebSocket Single Read Sampler': there is no connection to re-use)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have problem. I use Jmeter for test site, and after open connection after write/read samplers, after ~40 sec my socket closed and test stops. I can every 40 sec open connection or else?

**Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. First open a WebSocket Connection by executing `WebSocket Open Connection` and then tick `use existing connection` box in the `WebSocket Single Read Sampler`

   [image]
2. Or alternatively you can open a new connection each time you execute the `WebSocket Single Read Sampler`

   [image]

If the client you're trying to simulate opens a single connection and then executes multiple reads - you should go for option 1 and vice versa.

If the connection gets broken in the middle somewhere somehow you need to find a reason for this, i.e. [enable debug logging for WebSocket Samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />
```

and inspect [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries